# Cookies are required to use this site. HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse Cookies

Tags: cookies, rss, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am using the following code to make a HttpWebRequest and render the XML from the response stream.

`
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

req.Accept = "*/*";

req.Headers.Add("UA-CPU", "x86");

req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; MS-RTC LM 8)";

req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())

{

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))

{

```
  sb.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

}

}`

It was working fine on my local server and test server but on UAT server, i am getting the response as 'Cookies are required to use this site'. I don't understand why this is happenning. If I browse to the URL directly, valid XML is getting rendered but it doesn't work if use the above code. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the sever is expecting a cookie that you aren't sending.  After you browse to the URL in the browser, type this in the location bar to see the cookies: `javascript:alert(document.cookie);`

Comment: I did as you said - I get this message 

Internet Explorer cannot download. Unspecified error.

Comment: This turned out to be a custom error message from the site. I was able to resolve it by passing what it wanted